# How can we embed a Hosted payment page in a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I have a hosted payment page which needs to be used in Salesforce within a visualforce page. One way to do this is using iframe within Visualforce page but this does not work as it is not supported by Salesforce.

How can we achieve this?